# How we can draw a stroke for a custom path in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am making a custom path in SwiftUI and fill it with red color, I want to give a border or stroke for my path. How we can do this?

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
    
    Path { path in
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300), radius: 200, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
    }
    .fill(Color.red)

    
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to stroke and fill the path separately.  Here is one way to do it.

Assign your path to a variable, and then use that to fill it, and then overlay it with the same path stroked.  Note:  You need to use `path.closeSubpath()` to close your path, or only the arc will be stroked.

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View {
        let path = Path { path in
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300), radius: 200, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        path.fill(Color.red).overlay(path.stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: thanks, how we can make stroke line start and end be rounded?

Comment: `path.fill(Color.red).overlay(path.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round)))`

Answer (score 1):

First start by declaring a custom `Shape`. You only have to implement `func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path` :

```
struct Diamond: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let topMid = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
        let trailingMid = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY)
        let bottomMid = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY)
        let leadingMid = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY)
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: topMid)
        path.addLine(to: trailingMid)
        path.addLine(to: bottomMid)
        path.addLine(to: leadingMid)
        path.addLine(to: topMid)
        return path
    }
}
```

and then you can place in a `ZStack`: your background clipped to your custom shape and your custom shape with stroke applied:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .clipShape(Diamond())
            Diamond()
                .stroke(Color.purple, lineWidth: 4)
        }   .padding()
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget about path.closeSubpath() after drawing was finished to avoid gaps at the start point.

Comment: Where does this orange color come from?